mysqldump only output the .sql file, not .txt
From the docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab
...it seems that I should be able to dump the contents of my table as TSV data
When I use the following command:
mysqldump -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33306 --tab=/path/to/mysql/dump mydb mytable

It takes a while to complete and returns successfully, 0 status...
But:
ls -la /path/to/mysql/dump
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 anentropic  staff   128  9 Apr 13:33 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 anentropic  staff   128  9 Apr 13:29 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 anentropic  staff  3471  9 Apr 13:33 mytable.sql

I only have the .sql file containing the CREATE TABLE statement.
There is no .txt file containing the TSV data.
I have ~10.5M rows in that table.
How do I get this working?

Well I found the answer for myself and it's quite a WTF situation...
It appears that part that I omitted from my question is relevant: I am running MySQL server in a docker container, then running mysqldump from my host machine
It seems that the server writes the .txt files and mysqldump tool writes the .sql file
So the .sql file gets written to /path/to/mysql/dump on the host machine
And the .txt file gets written to /path/to/mysql/dump on the server filesystem, i.e. inside my docker container ‍♂️
So I need to come up with a path that makes sense in both filesystems, that I can also mount as a volume, so I can get the data dump back out of the container.
Update:
This compose.yaml config seems to work for that:
    command: --secure-file-priv=${PWD}/docker/mysql/dump
    volumes:
      - "./docker/mysql/dump:${PWD}/docker/mysql/dump:rw"


Yes, the documentation says mysqldump should be run on the same machine as the MySQL Server when you use this option, because the server writes .txt files in the directory you specify. It's using SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE which says "The file is created on the server host..."

Yeah I did get the idea to look into this and find the answer above after re-reading the docs. It still feels pretty weird that it writes the files to two different locations, and makes no distinction between local and remote filesystem, while still accepting hostname etc args to connect to remote server.
